# Angular, create DOM element after data is ready?

Tags: angular

I have a custom DOM element which is loaded by an external script. I need to pass this element an "event-id" parameter. I tried dynamic property but this isnt supported on the tag:

```
 <widget [event-id]="{{ event.id}}"></widget>
```

Inspecting widget, no event-id attribute is present because on initial load `event` is not set yet. If I manually set the ID it works.

I'm looking for a way to create the DOM element AFTER `event` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `*ngIf` like this:

```
<widget *ngIf="event?.id" [event-id]="{{ event.id}}"></widget>
```